# TextBlock foreground binding to IsEnabled

Tags: wpf

I wonder why is not the below `Style` changing the `TextBlock` `Foreground` color whenver `Checkbox` `IsChecked` status changes

```
<CheckBox Name="checkbox" IsChecked="True"/>

<TextBlock Foreground="LightGray" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=checkbox, Path=IsChecked}">
     <TextBlock.Style>
           <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                 <Style.Triggers>
                       <Trigger Property="TextBlock.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Gray" />
                       </Trigger>
                  </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
      </TextBlock.Style>
 </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have set ***local value that will always hold precedence over style triggers***. Move the property declaration within style and it will work because style triggers have higher precedence than style setters.

```
<TextBlock IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=checkbox, Path=IsChecked}">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/> <-- HERE
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="TextBlock.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="TextBlock.Foreground" Value="Gray" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Read on - [**Dependency Property Value Precedence**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

**Update** your existing style and add a default property value on the style of your `TextBlock`

```
<TextBlock Foreground="LightGray" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=checkbox, Path=IsChecked}">
     <TextBlock.Style>
           <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                 <Style.Triggers>
                       <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gray" />
                       </Trigger>
                  </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
           <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
      </TextBlock.Style>
 </TextBlock>
```